# How to add same filter to multiple data sources in tableau server?

Tags: tableau-api

I have three data sources A, B and C. All three of them have a field called `proxyid`. I cannot blend them because of usage of complex calculations. I have created three worksheets using these data sources respectively. I am creating a dashboard with these three worksheets. I want to use `proxyid` as a single filter which can span these three worksheets.

But currently I have three `proxyid` as filters each for their corresponding worksheet in dashboard. How can I use only one filter which can filter all three of the worksheet?

Answer (score 2):

You want to **apply a filter to related data sources** - which is an option if multiple data sources have a field with the same name and data type, or if you define explicit relationships between data sources from the Data menu.

Then you can simply show one filter control on your dashboard and set it to apply to all related data sources.

The parameter approach Andy mention works too, and used to be the main alternative before Tableau added this feature, which takes less effort to setup.

Comment: When I am using **apply filter to related data sources** , other data sources add this field as a secondary data source and the worksheets which uses that as a primary data source gives me errors. The reason of the errors being unsupported calculation in blend. I think I need to define the relationship between the data sources. Although I do have a field which I renamed to `proxyId` in all the data sources.

Comment: The field has to have same data type in each data source also, may have to be a dimension also. Why are you blending? Is that necessary?

Comment: Blending is not necessary and I am trying to avoid it. I have one to one relationship with data sources and worksheets. Thing is, when I take `proxyid` from say data source 1 and use **apply filter to related data sources** , the filter applied in other data sources uses the `proxyid` from data source 1 only. I was hoping that it should use`proxyid` from their respective data sources. Since the `proxyid` was used from data source 1 , other data sources use it as a secondary data source and thus they are blending it.

Comment: Can you post a simplified example to Tableau Public?

Comment: [Here](https://public.tableau.com/profile/prakhar.gajbhiye#!/vizhome/SampleStackoverflow/Sheet1) is a tableau public link. In sheet1 I have used `proxyid` as filter as **apply to related datasource**. I want in sheet2 the filter `proxyid` should come from its own data source.

Answer (score 1):

If only selecting one proxyid at a time you could flip your filter to be a parameter instead. For single select this works well and could filter all of your data sources in one.

Comment: proxyid fields keeps getting updated with new values. If I am not wrong, parameters cannot update its values dynamically. So if I am using **list** as allowable type and add values from proxyid, it will add all the values present currently in proxyid. But in future a new values of proxyid will  come which wont be present in the parameter list values. How can I proceed with this ?

Comment: Oh! nvm. I just saw the latest feature in tableau for dynamic parameters **when workbook opens** .